# How to select the nth adjacent element from a specific/selected element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

How to select the nth adjacent element from a specific/selected element using jQuery?
In the below example, how to select the 2nd adjacent element( `<li><a href="#">this is the 2nd adjacent element from active</a></li>`) from a selected/specific element(`<li class="active" ><a href="#">this is the current active element</a></li>`).
 
Please note: I can't use eq() or nth-child as the current active element  will change dynamically on every mouse click.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#select").on('click', function(){
    $("li").eq("2").addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
#select{ background:blue;}
ul{ list-style:none; float:left; clear:both}
ul li{float:left; clear:both;}
.active a{background:red;}
a{ color:#fff; background:#444; text-decoration:none; padding:5px; margin:2px; float:left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="select" href="#">click to select the 2nd adjacent element from current active </a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">111</a></li>
  <li class="active" ><a href="#">this is the current active element</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">333</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is the 2nd adjacent element from active</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">555</a></li>
 
</ul>
```

Comment: maybe $('li.active').next().next() ?

Comment: Thank you. But what if we have to select 50th or more ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to select the nth adjacent element from a specific/selected
>   element using jquery

If you want to select the 2nd next sibling of the current active element you could use `nextAll()`, similar to this:

```
$("li.active").nextAll().eq(2);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#select").on('click', function() {
  //console.log($("li.active").nextAll());
  $("li.active").removeClass('active').nextAll().eq(2).addClass("active");;
  });
});
```

```css
#select {
  background: blue;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  clear: both
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.active a {
  background: red;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="select" href="#">click to select the 2nd adjacent element from current active </a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">111</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">this is the current active element</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">333</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is the 2nd adjacent element from active</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">555</a></li>

</ul>
```

---

You still will need to apply rules as to how you want it to behave when it gets to the end and no siblings are left to select.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `eq()` with `nextAll()`
https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  function getNthSibling(parentSelector, n)
  {
    return $(parentSelector).nextAll().eq(n);
  }
  
  $('#select').on('click', function() {
    getNthSibling('li.active', 1).addClass('selected');
  });
  
});
```

```css
#select{ background:blue;}
ul{ list-style:none; float:left; clear:both}
ul li{float:left; clear:both;}
.active a{background:red;}
.selected a{background: green;}
a{ color:#fff; background:#444; text-decoration:none; padding:5px; margin:2px; float:left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="select" href="#">click to select the 2nd adjacent element from current active </a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">111</a></li>
  <li class="active" ><a href="#">this is the current active element</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">333</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">this is the 2nd adjacent element from active</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">555</a></li>
 
</ul>
```